# spring boot application properties staging and production

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm building a Spring Boot application and i would like to have multiple application properties with the same variables but different values (dev, staging and production) i already have my 3 files just i don't know how to use @PropertyResource and call to "envTarget" variable which was setted by maven

ApplicationProperties File

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-${envTarget:dev}.properties" })
```

Maven pom

```
    <configuration>
<systemPropertyVariables>
                            <envTarget>dev</envTarget>
    <!--                        <envTarget>staging</envTarget> -->
    <!--                        <envTarget>production</envTarget> -->
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you seen usage of profiles in spring : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: not yet, i'm going to try now with profiles, thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can have different property file for different environments.

syntax : application-{profile}.properties

e.g. application-dev.properties,application-qa.properties

Then try passing the profile as an arguement while running your spring boot application, spring.profiles.active=dev  .

See [Spring Boot support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for profile based properties.

Comment: its only couple of steps away..then shout out loud, spring rocks :-)